# Unable to consume Kafka messages within Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We have a Java application which consumes Kafka messages, using `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer`

We have created a Spring Boot application with a Spring-Kafka dependency, but are unable to read the messages within the new project. Have checked the obvious parameters, including hostname and port of the bootstrap servers (which the logs show are recognized), the group, the topic and that Spring Boot, like the original consumer, uses `StringDeserializer` . Here is our configuration file:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: hostname1:9092,hostname2:9092
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      group-id: our_group
      enable-auto-commit: false
      fetch-max-wait: 500
      max-poll-records: 1

kafka:
  topic:
    boot: topic.name
```

and the receiver:

```
@Component
public class Receiver {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);

    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.boot}")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord) {
        LOGGER.info("received payload='{}'", consumerRecord.toString());
        latch.countDown();
    }

}
```

Here is the code to start the Boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EmsDemoUsingSpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmsDemoUsingSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This exception is being caught:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Is there anything obvious I have overlooked?
What is the best way to debug this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in console?

Comment: no exceptions in the console

Comment: Do you really send records to that `topic.name`  ?

Comment: Can you show your Boot app as well? Is the `Receiver` class in the same package (or child package) as the boot app? `@KafkaListener` is enabled by `@EnableKafka` which boot should auto configure. Get an autoconfiguration report. Turn on DEBUG logging.

Comment: Couple of things Have you enabled kafka with `@EnableKafka` ?  and also try creating a bean of `ConsumerFactory` as mentioned here https://www.codenotfound.com/spring-kafka-consumer-producer-example.html

Comment: yes, have checked both the properties file in the original application, and a test harness we have to send messages.

Comment: edited question to show class which starts the Boot application, using @SpringBootApplication

Comment: Adding EnableKafka annotation to the start class under SpringBootApplication did not help

Comment: Even using ConsumerFactory as per the link you kindly sent (removing the Component annotation from the Receiver class, and instantiating it as a bean), does not help

Comment: Updated question with exception which is being logged

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too and what happens was that I could not connect to the server. You can change log level in the `application.properties` or `application.yml` to see more details. The demon is in the log..

```
logging:
  level:
    root: WARN
    org.springframework: INFO
    org.apache.kafka: DEBUG
```

I am told that Kafka is not able to handle name lookup and from my experience, the host to connect should almost always be FQDN names(with domain name and all). In my case, I think I haven't set the domain in my virtual box and it is not possible to find my guest box, even we are in the same subnet and `ping` works.

Also, I create another main class for Kafka part and it turns out wrong. It is not good practice and you should annotate the application main class with `@EnableKafka` and just put the settings in the yml file, and they should be loaded. No need for another configuration class.

My consumer:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class KafkaConsumer {
    @KafkaListener(topics={"testtopic"})
    public void listen(@Payload String message) {
        log.info("Received message is {}", message);
    }
}
```

My application:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;

@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableKafka    // <----- I only had to add this line
public class SomeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SomeApplication.class, args);
        log.info("Application launched. ");
    }
}
```

My config yml:

```
logging:
  level:
    root: WARN
    org.springframework: INFO
    org.apache.kafka: DEBUG

spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: <FQDN names here:9092>
    consumer:
      group-id: <unique-group-id>
      enable-auto-commit: false # never ack messsage when it is received.
    listener:
      ack-mode: manual # I am responsible to ack the messages
```

And launch the application. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you may have missed `KafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean which needs to be specified in `@Configuration` file

```
@Bean
KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>>
kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
  factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String>(new HashMap<String,Object>((Map)consumerConfig)));
  factory.setConcurrency(concurrentConsumerCount);
  factory.setBatchListener(true);
  return factory;
}
```

Also for consumer specify `KafkaListenerContainerFactory` like 
`@KafkaListener(topics = ("${kafka.topic.boot}"), containerFactory = "kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory"`